# How to combine predicates in a LINQ query for Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, predicate

In the source code I am currently working with there is a lot of redundancy when querying information from our repository with Entity Framework. I created a function that returns an expression that looks something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<SourceObject, bool>> IsAwesome()
{
    return t => t.Collection1.Any(tr => /* very long condition */) ||
                t.Collection2.Any(tr => /* very long condition */) ||
                t.Collection3.Any(tr => /* very long condition */) ||
                t.Collection4.Any(tr => /* very long condition */);
}
```

Using this function in several Where queries already cleaned-up the code a bit, but I still have the same very long condition for each of the four collections in my SourceObject. The four collections have different data types, but all of them implement the same shared interface. I tried to write something like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<SourceObject, bool>> IsAwesome()
{
    Func<ICollectionObject, bool> isAwesome = tr => /* very long condition */;

    return t => t.Collection1.Any(isAwesome) ||
                t.Collection2.Any(isAwesome) ||
                t.Collection3.Any(isAwesome) ||
                t.Collection4.Any(isAwesome);
}
```

It compiles flawlessly, but when the program is executed and the query against our data base happens, I get the following exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Expression of type 'System.Func`2[ICollectionObject,System.Boolean]'   cannot be used for parameter of type   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ICollectionObject,System.Boolean]]' of method  'Boolean Any[ICollectionObject](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[ICollectionObject],  System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[ICollectionObject,System.Boolean]])' (Parameter  'arg1')'
```

Is there a way to improve my function and remove the redundancy?

I tried to write extensions, local functions, local expressions, etc. They all compile, but they all lead to same exception.

Comment: You need to pass `Expression`s to EF so that the expression may be "parsed" and generate SQL. `Func` just doesn't cut it. Change `Func<ICollectionObject, bool> isAwesome = ...` to `Expression<Func<ICollectionObject, bool>> isAwesome = ...` and it should() work,

Comment: SourceObject is an object from our repository and the four collections are lists in this object. The LINQ queries on these collections are therefore operating on IEnumerable and only accept Funcs are predicates. Is there a way to use expressions even if LINQ wants Funcs?

Comment: We would need to see a more realistic example of your code and a more detailed explanation with that info.

Comment: Add an Extension Method to the SourceObject as `IsAwesome()` and call as `t.Collection1.Any(tr => tr.IsAwesome())`

Comment: I tried your idea, @SathishGuruV, but it results in an exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression '[FULL EXPRESSION]' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.'

Comment: Linq-to-Entities only supports some of the capabilities of Linq. You could try just one collection as t.Collection1.ToList().Any(isAwesome), removing your ORs for now, and see if that works. The ToList() will run the SQL statement and afterwards give you all the capabilities of Linq. However you would be loading the complete dataset without your conditions so it's for troubleshooting only.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit) and it's `ExpandableAttribute`.

Configure `DbContextOptions`:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

And specify new extension methods:

```cs
public static class MyExtensions
{
    [Expandable(nameof(SourceObjectIsAwesomeImpl))]
    public static bool IsAwesome(this SourceObject t)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    [Expandable(nameof(CollectionObjectIsAwesomeImpl))]
    public static bool IsAwesome<T>(this T t)
        where T: ICollectionObject
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    private static Expression<Func<SourceObject, bool>> SourceObjectIsAwesomeImpl()
    {
        return t => t.Collection1.Any(x => x.isAwesome()) ||
                    t.Collection2.Any(x => x.isAwesome()) ||
                    t.Collection3.Any(x => x.isAwesome()) ||
                    t.Collection4.Any(x => x.isAwesome());
    }

    private static Expression<Func<ICollectionObject, bool>> CollectionObjectIsAwesomeImpl()
    {
        return t => /* very long condition */;
    }    
}
```